# How to reading and Output [FILTERED] value from parameters in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest

I am using `curl` to post json to my example service. I am posting json to the service as shown below

```
curl \
> -i \
> -H "Accept: application/json" \
> -H "Content-type: application/json" \
> -X POST \
> -d '{"email":"micky@minn.com","full_names":"Inisne Dats", "password": "oasswn"}' http://localhost:3000/api/admin_users
```

Below is my method thats responsible for creating and saving the new Active record Object

```
def create
        user = AdminUser.new(white_list)    
        if user.save
            head 200
        else
            puts user.errors.full_messages
            head 500
        end

end
```

My Whitelist method below

```
private
    def white_list
        params.require(:admin_user).permit(:email,:full_names,:password)
    end
```

The problem is that this code never saves because the password is **FILTERED**, I have inspected the parameters and this is the output;

```
 {"email"=>"micky@minn.com", "full_names"=>"Inisne Dats", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "admin_user"=>{"email"=>"micky@minn.com", "full_names"=>"Inisne Dats"}}
```

Can anyone help show me how to retrieve the filtered password and use it once the parameters reach the controller method **create**.  Or I'm I using whitelisting feature wrong?

Comment: It is simply filtering the password in the logs so it's not logging actual passwords.  Your issue is more than likely that you're using `has_secure_password` and are not passing `password_confirmation` as a parameter.  What are the errors on the admin user?

Comment: Password can't be blank is the only error

Comment: in the whitelist method allow `password_confirmation` and send that in your curl post, with the same value as password.

Comment: I have updated that to 'private
 def white_list
  params.require(:admin_user).permit(:email,:full_names,:password, :password_confirmation)
 end'

Comment: and made a fresh post with `'{"email":"micky@minn.com","full_names":"Inisne Dats", "password": "oasswn","password_confirmation":"oasswn"}' ` Same problem, Password confirmation is filtered.

Comment: Having filtered in the logs isn't the error.  Do you still get password can't be blank as the error on user? Are you using has_secure_password? or devise? or clearance?

Comment: I am using `has_secure_password`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110915/discussion-between-isaac-chambers-and-j-dexx).

Answer (score 0):

@j-dexx gave me this answer. I had to wrap the parameters with a root `"admin_user"` key like so:

```
{ "admin_user":
  { "email": "micky@minn.com",
    "full_names": "Inisne Dats",
    "password": "oasswn",
    "password_confirmation": "oasswn"
  }
}
```

...so I changed my post request to:

```
curl \
> -i \
> -H "Accept: application/json" \
> -H "Content-type: application/json" \
> -X POST \
> -d '{"admin_user":{"email":"micky@minn.com","full_names":"Inisne Dats","password":"oasswn","password_confirmation":"oasswn"}}' http://localhost:3000/api/admin_users
```

That did the trick!